# Picasa web albums with GPS Sign-in

Tags: android, google-play-services, picasa

I am trying to access Picasa Web Albums from an Android app using Google API (gdata). I succeeded in doing so after authenticating by AndroidAccount.AccountManager.getAuthToken.

I now wish to do the same but after authenticating with the new Google Sign-In support in Google Play Services v 8.3.0 (and thus avoiding the GET_ACCOUNTS permission).

I can't figure out how to obtain an authToken to pass to PWA from the new GoogleSignInAccount. Any one has any insights?